# How do I make a thread stop another thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I've basically just found out that multithreading programming exists and I'm having fun blindly playing around with the concept.

What I'm trying to do is a timer that gets checked dynamically every second, while the user keeps interacting with the program in some form.

This is what I was able to accomplish so far:

```
void* timer (void* threadToStop)
{
    pthread_t* threadName = threadToStop;

    time_t startTime = time(NULL);
    time_t currentTime;
    int elapsedTime;
    int remainingTime;

    do {

        if (currentTime != time(NULL)) 
        {
            currentTime = time(NULL);
            elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
            remainingTime = 10 - elapsedTime;
            printf("%d ", remainingTime);
            fflush(stdout);
        }

    } while (remainingTime > 0);

    pthread_cancel(*threadName);

    return NULL;
}

void* func (void* vargp)
{
    getchar();

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{

    pthread_t funcId;
    pthread_create(&funcId, NULL, func, NULL);

    pthread_t timerId;
    pthread_create(&timerId, NULL, timer, &funcId);

    pthread_join(funcId, NULL); 

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Two threads get created from two different functions and start running concurrently.

"`func`" is just a dummy function that asks the user to input a character. It's just a way to have the user interacting with the program while the timer is running in the background.

"`timer`" is self-explanatory: it's the function that starts and updates the timer every second. When this thread gets created, it also gets `func`'s thread id as an argument. When time's up, I call the `pthread_cancel` function in order to stop `func`'s thread using its id.

This program works for the most part: the timer keeps running while I'm able to input characters in the console, and when I press the enter key the `pthread_join` function kicks in and the main function reaches the end. However, when the timer runs out, the `func` thread doesn't get cancelled and I'm having a hard time figuring out why.

Comment: Please do not change the question after comments and/or answers have been given, as this might render them ununderstandable. Update your question with additions instead. I will rollback your last change though.

Comment: Sorry about that, still a newbie around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code misses to initialise `currentTime`, before using it:

```
  time_t currentTime;
  int elapsedTime;
  int remainingTime;

  do {

    if (currentTime != time(NULL))
```

---

A thread only gets cancelled when passing or "sitting on" a so called *Cancellation Point*.

`getchar()` is not necessarily a cancellation point.

A list of mandatory and optional cancellation points for POSIX threads is [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_05_02).

---

To shed some light on what is really going on replace:

```
  pthread_cancel(...);
```

by:

```
  errno = pthread_cancel(...);
  if (0 != errno)
  {
    perror("pthread_cancel() failed");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't notice that blunder.
By the way, does this mean that threads can be stopped only under the right conditions? Isn't there a way to do what I'm trying to (which is unconditionally and abruptly stop any possible thread when time's over)?

Comment: "*does this mean that threads can be stopped only under the right conditions*" yes. Still, one should try to design code in a way that using `pthread_cancel()` is not necessary at all. In more complex scenarios like yours it is very easy to run into any sort of trouble when trying to cancel a thread due to the nature of asynchronicity. One mostly never really knows when and where the thread "just ends", and with this leaving the system in an not well defined state or at least unknown state.

Comment: Isn't there any alternative way go about this problem? I had thought of a flag of some sort, but still I wouldn't be able to check that flag while the thread is sitting on a function such as getchar. It wouldn't really be checked in real-time at any time. That's the reason I thought of a more drastic solution with thread cancelation.

Comment: @Gian: To make a blocking function return, a common approach is to send the blocking thread a signal. The function then typically will return indicating an error and setting `errno` to `EINTR`. Signalling makes multithreading even more fun. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will look into it!